RS232 for PCB Design and Connectors
I'm a junior EE and have been tasked to create a PCB that interfaces with a microcontroller from another PCB (PCB 1) to my PCB (PCB 2). A connector passes through all signals from PCB 1 to PCB 2, these include RS232 TX and RX.
My query:
How would I wire these two TX and RX lines to a connector? For RS232, I've seen other signals and such so I'm confused.
From the info doc for PCB 1, the RS232 lines are a serial debug port with a bit rate of 250 kbps with voltage levels accurate to EIA/TIA-232 and an optional mounting variant to 3V3-TTL.
Would greatly appreciate any help!

You have 3 different questions. Please create three different threads, one for each question. Otherwise, people will vote to close this thread.

Meh, the serial questions (note RS232 is a line signaling and pinout standard, and says very little about actual signal timing and protocol used thereon) go together well enough. The signal quality / EMC questions likely should be spun off, however. That said, given the basic nature of question 2, perhaps three would be better?

Are there any mechanical constraints and limitations? For instance, are you looking for a connection where a long cable can be placed? Are the boards going to be vertically stacked?

my apologies for the multiple Qs, fixed it for just one.
@Colin no mechanical constraints or limitations. just something where a cable harness can be made reasonably (not complicated)

At what level you are asking this? You can use any connector you want, and draw standard copper traces on PCB between connector and RS-232 physical interface chip. Which PHY and bit rate you are using? Also, RS-422 tag is unrelated if you don't use it. And RS-232 is specifically used to avoid EMI.

edited to put some more info that I think is important.

First, let's understand something. RS-232 is a communication standard that carries serial TX/RX signals as well as a number of sideband signals for modem control. It's a very old standard, dating from the early 1960s. RS-232 is intended for box-to-box cabling in noisy environments (such as TTY to modem). To make it robust it supports much higher voltage levels (+/-12V) than the 3.3V/5V 'logic' levels used by microcontrollers. Read a bit more here: https://www.virtual-serial-port.org/article/what-is-serial-port/rs232-pinout/
RS-232 uses a DB25 connector, a large, D-shaped connector that, like RS-232, has been use since the mid-20th century. This carries TX/RX and the full complement of modem control signals. Later, PC computers introduced the smaller DE9 (aka "DB9") connector with fewer sideband signals.
Once the RS-232 signals reach the board, they are translated between the +/-12V world to logic levels using specialty ICs. Historical ones include the MC1488 and MC1489. Newer ones exist that include charge pumps for the higher +/-V rails, avoiding the need for +/-12V supplies.
Both DB25 and DE9 are large connectors by today's standards; you won't find them on computers anymore. Instead, PC users use USB to serial adapters if they need a serial port.
Back to your question. Do you really need RS-232? If your intention is to connect two boards in the same box, you don't need it. You can instead connect the two boards directly using logic-level ('TTL') UART TX and RX. Then you don't need a TTL-to-RS-232 level shifter or the bulky connectors.
I suggest that your boards follow the pinout of a common USB-to-TTL serial adapter, like this one from Digilent: https://digilent.com/reference/pmod/pmodusbuart/reference-manual. Then you have the option of connecting your microcontroller boards to a PC for debug. This is a 6-pin connector that includes not only TX and RX but also RTS/CTS for handshaking. You should check with your software folks if they will need the handshake, especially if you intend to use higher UART baud rates.

RS-232 was never even intended to go up to 250 kbps, but it's approximately the  maximum possible that may not even violate the slew rate or minimum amplitude specs much. As long as the RS-232 interface chip is specified to 250kbps it will be fine.
But it really requires no special handling. It can go a few meters through random cabling so it can surely pass few centimeters on PCB as long as you follow otherwise normal digital signal routing methods.
